# Why need "any of" in "The fingers are any of the digits of the hand"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> The fingers are any of the digits of the hand, ....

I saw the sentence from [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/finger).

In my view, the sentence should be written as:

> The fingers are the digits of the hand,...

It's because *any* suggest **singular**, but *the fingers* are **plural**.

Any thought?

Comment: Any of the digits are fingers. “Any”  in the sense of “each one.” Each digit is a finger.

Comment: @user070221, I am still confusing. "Any of the digits are fingers." and "The fingers are any of the digits of the hand" might be grammatical, but it doesn't seem logical.